# Are there spiders in Metamorphosis?

Tags: metamorphosis

I recently bought [Metamorphosis](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1025410/Metamorphosis/), but after finding some cobwebs in an early level, I'm worried there might be spiders in the game that may or may not trigger my arachnophobia.

Are there spiders in Metamorphosis?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are spiders in this game. I couldn't tell you how frequently they appear, but they definitely exist in this game. Based on images the spiders seem to be the hairless variety, similar to Skyrim's Frostbite spiders.

I suppose encountering arachnids to be expected based on a game where you regularly encounter other insects.

If you're feeling brave you can see it yourself from the image hosted front-and-center in this game review: https://www.pcinvasion.com/metamorphosis-review-between-angels-and-insects/